# Destroy called locally but Delete called on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

EDIT: Per tdooner, I did some more testing with the Heroku rails console. Creating a part, a line item with that part, and then attempting to destroy results in a rollback both locally and on Heroku. So I know the logic is working fine, but why is delete called rather than destroy? (I think that's what's happening anyways. Things are working fine locally, but not on heroku...) I'm lost.

It seems as if my before_destroy method is successfully working locally, but not on Heroku.

Before Parts are deleted by a user, the app checks to see if a corresponding Line Item exists in a WorkOrder, and if so disallow the action.

Now, if I try to **destroy** a Part in the console, the before_destroy method is respected, and the logs show a rollback (same as when Parts are deleted locally). If I **delete** a Part in the console, the Part is deleted without error. To my inexperienced eye, it seems as if the Part is being deleted on Heroku, vs being destroyed, even though the logs say #destroy is being called.

The Delete function is rails generated and looks like so
`<%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")), part_path(part), :method => :delete`.

I know there is a difference between delete and destroy in regards to a has_many, :through relation, but am not certain if that plays in here.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**Part.rb**

```
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items
  before_destroy :ensure_not_referenced_by_line_item #works fine locally

  def ensure_not_referenced_by_line_item
    if ( LineItem.any? { |li| li.part_id == self.partnum } )
      errors.add(:base, "Cannot delete this part, as it is referenced in a work order.")
      return false
    end
  end
 end
```

**LineItem.rb**

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :part
```

**WorkOrder.rb**

```
class WorkOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :parts, :through => :line_items
```

**Local Webrick Logs**

```
Started DELETE "/parts/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-08 18:36:14 -0500
Processing by PartsController#destroy as HTML
  Part Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" WHERE "parts"."id" = $1 ORDER BY partnum ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", "2"]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  LineItem Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items"
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/parts
```

**Heroku Logs**

```
: Started DELETE "/parts/25" for x.x.x at 2014-03-08 23:38:45 +0000
: Processing by PartsController#destroy as HTML
: Processing by PartsController#destroy as HTML
:   Part Load (46.6ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" WHERE "parts"."id" = $1 ORDER BY partnum ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", "25"]]
:   Part Load (46.6ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" WHERE "parts"."id" = $1 ORDER BY partnum ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", "25"]]
:    (6.9ms)  BEGIN
:    (6.9ms)  BEGIN
:   LineItem Load (4.3ms)  SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items"
:   LineItem Load (4.3ms)  SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items"
:   SQL (2.1ms)  DELETE FROM "parts" WHERE "parts"."id" = $1  [["id", 25]]
:   SQL (2.1ms)  DELETE FROM "parts" WHERE "parts"."id" = $1  [["id", 25]]
:    (3.7ms)  COMMIT
:    (3.7ms)  COMMIT
: Redirected to ....herokuapp.com/parts
```

Comment: Can you post the `Part#ensure_not_referenced_by_line_item` implementation, as well as what happens if you do the following locally and on heroku, in a `rails console`: 1) create a `Part`, 2) create a `LineItem` with `part_id` set to the part's ID, 3) destroy the part. Thanks!

Comment: Try testing in `heroku run rails console`, and also using `if LineItem.find_by(part_id: self.partnum)` instead of loading every line item.

Comment: Thanks, that's much more concise. I did test on both Heroku and locally, and it appears the logic works as designed (attempting to destroy a part fails if a line item exists). The question, I believe, is why Delete would be called on Heroku vs Destroy locally. I could be way off base, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `has_many :line_items` matches on the `Part.id` field, but your test to see if something is referenced is checking a partnum field.  Are you sure the id and partnum are always the same?  I suspect that they aren't in the data stored within Heroku.

In addition, your validation doesn't do what you think it does.

Your `Parts#ensure_not_referenced_by_line_item` function will always return false.  The if statement will either be true, in which case you explicitly return false, or the if statement will be false, in which case the function implicitly return false (the value of the function is the value of the last operation, which is the if statement, which is false).

A better way to write it would be

```
def ensure_not_referenced_by_line_item
  not(LineItem.exists?(part_id: self.id))
end
```

Note that in this re-write, I'm referencing the self.id, not self.partnum

Comment: Perfect. I completely missed both the id/partnum mismatch and the return true. Thanks much!